# How to use mobile-ffmpeg and shared library (.so) ffmpeg together?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have problem with using aar mobile-ffmpeg (https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) and build .so library ffmpeg for oboe (Android NDK), when I try to use them together I get this error
**by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "avpriv_init_elbg" referenced by ... ==/lib/x86/libavfilter.so"**

If I disable one of this, everything works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I created folder 'lib',so folder where store libraries in mobile-ffmpeg, in my project instead of directory 'libs' and put mobile-ffmpeg shared libraries in folder 'lib'.